# /index.php/, /index.php?/, /?/ in codeigniter urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Although we've redirected `index.php` to root, still we are getting inner page URLs in following 4 versions:

```
https://example.com/articles [/index.php/articles, /index.php?/articles & /?/articles]
```

Would anyone explain why?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*) example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|phpinfo\.php|Charts|assets|uploads|userfiles|c‌​ustomer-uploads|appl‌​ication|sitemap\.xml‌​|sitemap\.html|robot‌​s\.txt|gyan\.rss) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You'll have to show your .htaccess file. Otherwise it's impossible to guess what is wrong with it.

Comment: *Where* are you getting them?

Comment: Our .htaccess is as follows:                                                    RewriteEngine on                                                                      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on                                                         RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.com RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|phpinfo\.php|Charts|assets|uploads|userfiles|customer-uploads|application|sitemap\.xml|sitemap\.html|robots\.txt|gyan\.rss)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Cannot you edit your own question to put the `.htaccess` directly inside? Just think to indent every line with 4 spaces to let it show as some code?

Comment: You still didn't answer where these URLs are coming from. Are they created by codeigniter? Are they in hard-coded or DB content? Are they from other sites/search results? You can't be getting different rewrite outputs from exactly the same input, so something is causing these variations before rewriting is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this simpler method

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php| (.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```